Leader lines moving after reopening project
I have a graphics layer containing my callouts with leader lines.

After saving my project, and reopening it, the leader lines have moved to a completely different location, halfway across the state.

I tried troubleshooting it by trying different types of text boxes (hence the three call outs) but that didn't appear to be the issue. This also only happens on this project, and all other projects have their leader lines working correctly.
Is there some kind of setting, or graphics property that would cause this issue that happens to be turned on for this project?

What happens if you zoom in to the same extent as in the first picture?

@SonofaBeach When I zoom in, the leader is moved like in the second picture, going off screen.

Are these call outs in a LAYOUT or the MAP...?

@Hornbydd These are all on the map itself

I can't replicate the issue and you say its only one project, bin it and start again? Copy layers into a new blank project before bin it?

@Hornbydd Thanks Hornbydd, I think that is going to be the only route for us to take.

I have not proven it has to do with this issue but getting a transformation warning.
